# If statement not working correctly with combobox value

Tags: vba, excel

Below is my vba code for after the user selects data from 3 comboboxes and adds text to 3 more fields.  I am trying to select a sheet based on the value of a combobox, ("List1" below).  However, the code continues through both sheets despite the List1.Value being correct.  How can I make it select the correct sheet?

```
Private Sub OKPrint_Click()

Dim LastRow As Long, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

ChDir ("My Directory")

On Error Resume Next

Set wb = Workbooks("Workbook in Question")

If wb Is Nothing Then
    Workbooks.Open ("My Directory + the Workbook in Question")
    Set wb = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
Else

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

ws.Select

LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = List1.Value
ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = List2.Value
ws.Range("C" & LastRow).Value = List3.Value
ws.Range("D" & LastRow).Value = Input1.Value
ws.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = Input2.Value
ws.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = Input3.Value

If List1.Value = "Value1" Or "Value2" Then

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")

    ws.Range("C15").Value = List1.Value
    ws.Range("C17").Value = List2.Value
    ws.Range("C18").Value = List3.Value
    ws.Range("C16").Value = Input1.Value
    ws.Range("C19") = "a bit of text"
    ws.Range("C20").Value = Input2.Value
    ws.PrintOut

Else

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet3")

    ws.Range("C15").Value = List1.Value
    ws.Range("C17").Value = List2.Value
    ws.Range("C18").Value = List3.Value
    ws.Range("C16").Value = Input1.Value
    ws.Range("C19") = "a bit of text"
    ws.Range("C20").Value = Input2.Value
    ws.PrintOut
End If



LocAmt.Value = Null
ValDt.Value = Null
ToDt.Value = Null

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a snap shot of the options in the Combobox, for a more effective solution !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List1.Value = "Value1" Or "Value2" is not correct.

it should be:

List1.Value = "Value1" Or List1.Value = "Value2"

Every side of an Or expression is a value that is evaluated as a boolean (true or false). "Value2" is not a boolean but a string

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!!